# Help installing Nvidia CUDA on WSL2

Tags: cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to follow this guide but it's not working. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#known-limitations

System requirements met:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 (oe-user@oe-host) (gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC)) #1 SMP Wed Oct 28 23:40:43 UTC 2020
```

On the windows side, installed the latest version: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl

Installed cuda toolkit per instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit-11-2
```

Attempting to run BlackScholes example:

```
cd /usr/local/cuda/samples/4_Finance/BlackScholes
sudo make
./BlackScholes
[./BlackScholes] - Starting...
CUDA error at ../../common/inc/helper_cuda.h:779 code=100(cudaErrorNoDevice) "cudaGetDeviceCount(&device_count)"
```

Nvidia-smi:

```
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem, except I get error code 35 instead of 100. I followed the post in the answer, yet I still get the same error after installing 11.0 and 10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having similar issues and I had to make sure that my Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview was set to Dev option.  I had set this to Beta, and that is incorrect.

I then found this guide, which was very helpful: https://dinhanhthi.com/docker-wsl2-windows/#wsl-%2B-windows

Then this guide, which got the toolkits to work: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-install-the-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-11-in-wsl2-88292cf4ab77

I also read somewhere, that I cannot find now, that Cuda Toolkit 11-0 & 10-2 is what you need. Apparently 11-2 does not work.

I spent about 3 weeks trying to figure all this out for myself, and I hope it proves useful for you.

EDIT: I still cannot get Docker to work, but the GPU is being read and used by TensorFlow, and `nvidia-smi` works.